# JQuery extension of nested objects - setting props on extension also changes the original extended object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, extend

I'm trying to create an object by extending two others.

I create a settings object by extending the "options" and "default" objects.
This works but later what i set `settings.limit = 1000`, my "`default.limit`" will also be set to 1000.

Is this behaviour by design? If yes what's the reasoning and how can I avoid this?

Here's also the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq3d55bn/

```
var defaults = { validate: false, limit: { a: 1, b: 2 }, name: "foo" };
var options = { validate: true, name: "bar" };

// Merge defaults and options, without modifying defaults
var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );
console.log(settings);//everything is correct here
var limit = settings.limit;
limit.a = 1000;
console.log('after',defaults);//here defaults.limit = 1000 !?!?!
```

Comment: The `jQuery.extend()` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) says _Merge defaults and options, without modifying the defaults_ , so I also wonder about the result. I created another fiddle based on the last example on the jQuery documentation page and get the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/xyt8nsvx/

Answer (score 0):

I did not expect this behavior either, but you can avoid it by replacing

```
var limit = settings.limit;
limit.a = 1000;
```

with

```
settings.limit = { a: 1000, b: settings.limit.b };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xyt8nsvx/1/